# Finding a specific link in a webpage

Tags: java, html, web, hyperlink, ftp

I'm writing a program that has to find a specific link from a webpage, so I connect to the webpage and read in the HTML. I'm not sure what to do next.

The link is always in the same place and has the same link text. The link is always a link to a FTP if that helps.

Here is my code:

```
URL exchange = new URL("**********"+codeArr[i]);

System.out.println(exchange);

URLConnection connection = exchange.openConnection();

BufferedReader URLIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Java? Could you post what you have done so far.

Comment: I've updated my post